# Como manter o visual padrão do TextBox a mudar o valor da propriedade ReadOnly?

Tags: c#, winforms, aplicação-desktop

Se o valor da propriedade `ReadOnly` de um `TextBox` for `false` significa que eu posso alterar o conteúdo. Entretanto, quando o valor é `true` o conteúdo não pode mais ser alterado, porem, quando mudamos o valor do `ReadOnly` para `true` o visual do `TextBox` e alterado, veja abaixo na imagem.

**Um** `TextBox` **com a sua propriedade** `ReadOnly` **definida para** `true`**:**

[image: Imagem mostrando o visual de um TextBox]

Caso contrario, o visual do `TextBox` fica normal, veja abaixo na imagem.

**Um** `TextBox` **com a sua propriedade** `ReadOnly` **definida para** `false` (*este é o visual padrão*)**:**

[image: Imagem mostrando o visual de um TextBox]

Aqui segue o código que muda o valor da propriedade `ReadOnly` para ser reproduzido:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBoxExemplo.ReadOnly)
    {
        textBoxExemplo.ReadOnly = false;                
    }
    else
    {
        textBoxExemplo.ReadOnly = true;               
    }
}
```

A mudança do visual talvez seja para indicar que o campo pode sofrer alterações, contudo, eu gostaria de manter o visual padrão quando defino a propriedade `ReadOnly` para `true`, como posso fazer isto programaticamente?

Comment: Isso funciona, se você não conseguir entender mais tarde eu volto e traduzo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039901/setting-a-read-only-textbox-default-backcolor

Comment: @FelipeAssunção adaptei o exemplo da resposta do link que vc me mandou. Funcionou, porem a cor é alterada quando o `textbox` recebe foco através do mouse, mas volta ao normal quando ele perde o foco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo o conteúdo do link citado pelo @Felipe Assunção pude fazer com que o `TextBox` mantenha o visual padrão quando a propriedade `ReadOnly` era definida para `true`.

Manipulando diretamente os eventos `ReadOnlyChanged` e `BackColorChanged` do `TextBox`, pode-se impedir que a cor de fundo do `TextBox` ao ativar o `ReadOnly` seja alterada e também é possível adicionar um critério de alteração da cor, veja a adaptação abaixo.

**1° solução** (Eventos `ReadOnlyChanged` e `BackColorChanged`)**:**

```
private void textBoxExemplo_ReadOnlyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    suprimiMudancaBackColor = true;
    textBoxExemplo.BackColor = textBoxExemplo.ReadOnly ? Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control) : atualBackColor;
    suprimiMudancaBackColor = false;
}

private void textBoxExemplo_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (suprimiMudancaBackColor) 
        return;

    atualBackColor = textBoxExemplo.BackColor;
}
```

É necessário definir a variável  `Color atualBackColor;` de tipo `Color`, que irar armazenar temporariamente a cor padrão do `TextBox` e a variável `bool suprimiMudancaBackColor;` respontavel por suprimir a alteração da cor de fundo do `TexBox`, ambas como globais.

**Explicação do resultado.**

O resultado desta solução é que o `TextBox` ira manter a cor padrão quando a propriedade `ReadOnly` for definida para `true`, porem, quando o usuário clicar sobre o `TexBox` com o `ReadOnly` ativo a cor dele irar mudar através do método [FromKnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) da classe `Color` utilizando uma cor predefinida que é representada pelo elemento [KnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.knowncolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e quando o usuário clicar fora do `TextBox` (quando o ele perder o foco) ira definir a cor para cor padrão novamente ou seja branco.

Nota:

> Talvez esta forma seja mais trabalhosa quando se tiver vários
>   `TextBox`, porem ela é mais eficiente.

Fonte: [Setting a read only Textbox default Backcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039901/setting-a-read-only-textbox-default-backcolor)

**2° solução** (método `mudarReadOnly`)**:**

Uma segunda solução que eu elaborei foi criar um método para ser utilizado no evento **Loard** do formulário, veja abaixo:

```
private void mudarReadOnly(TextBox textBox, bool readOnly) 
{
    Color backColorPadrao = textBox.BackColor;
    textBox.ReadOnly = readOnly;
    textBox.BackColor = backColorPadrao;
}
```

**Explicação do resultado.**

Ele recebe dois parâmetros, um `TextBox` e a opção que irar ativar o desativar o `ReadOnly` e antes dele fazer a alteração do `ReadOnly` ele armazena a cor padrão e depois redefine a cor do `TextBox` através da cor armazenada e ira sempre manter a cor branca do `TextBox`.

Nota:

> Este método pode ser melhorado, mas, o objetivo é trabalhar com vários
>   `TextBox` em um formulário.

Answer (score 2):

Basta apenas selecionar o seu `texBox` e ir em suas propriedades e mudar a propriedade `BackColor` para `White`. Caso queira fazer isso via código poderá ser adicionar no `Load` do seu `Form`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Pois esta é uma maneira bem simples de se obter o mesmo resultado de quando o seu texBox estar com o `ReadOnly` igual a `false`. Porém para o usuário é melhor que ele fique realmente com a coloração em tons de cinzas, pois é uma forma visual dele identificar que aquele campos não poderá ser editado, como também é um recurso que estar presente em praticamente todos os sistemas.

Comment: Já consegui resolver aqui, obrigado pela resposta, postarei uma resposta minha para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu programo em VB6, e isto não acontece quando mudo o ReadOnly, tente mudar o "BackColor" do text em tempo de execução como citou o Dener Carvalho, se isto não funcionar, mude a aparência dele de 3D para FLAT, que deve ser um flag de objetos win32!

Comment: Funciona se eu mudar o *BackColor*, `textBoxExemplo.BackColor = Color.White;`